# ShareThis social icons for particular article

Tags: facebook-social-plugins, sharethis

I want to add ShareThis social icons into a page with multiple articles, currently I have those icons show on each articles, for example 5 articles in a page, each article have a facebook's share with counter, if I want to share the 3rd article and click share, facebook will share this link with the first article content instead of 3rd article content, anyone can help on this?

I copied below code from ShareThis and pasted in a php loop:

```
<span class='st_sharethis_hcount' displayText='ShareThis'></span>
<span class='st_facebook_hcount' displayText='Facebook'></span>
<span class='st_twitter_hcount' displayText='Tweet'></span>
<span class='st_linkedin_hcount' displayText='LinkedIn'></span>
<span class='st_googleplus_hcount' displayText='Google +'></span>
<span class='st_email_hcount' displayText='Email'></span>
```

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

You have to create the dynamic article url, separate for each article and pass this url to the span tag as below.

```
<span class="st_sharethis_hcount" st_url="article url" st_title="article title"></span>
```

Add extra parameter in you code.
st_url="article url"

If you want any more help. Please check it on below link.

http://support.sharethis.com/customer/portal/articles/475079-share-properties-and-sharing-custom-information#Properties_Tags